# Have the vending machine inventory display when the Admin button is clicked

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to get the "Admin" button to display the current inventory of the products in the vending machine as well as the cash balance when clicked, but I can not seem to figure out how. I initially tried using a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog but everything I tried with it did not work.

Error:

> cannot find symbol symbol: method getInv(Dispenser) location: class VendingMachine.ButtonHandler ---- (Alt-Enter shows hints)

**Main Class**

```
package vendingmachine;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VendingMachine extends JFrame {
//Constants
private static final int WIDTH = 500;
private static final int HEIGHT = 850;

//Object Variables
private JLabel headingL, selectionL;
private JButton candyB, chipsB, gumB, cookiesB, exitB, adminB;
private ButtonHandler bHandler;

//Instance Variables
private Register register = new Register();
private static Dispenser candy = new Dispenser();
private static Dispenser chips = new Dispenser(5,2);
private static Dispenser gum = new Dispenser(20,1);
private static Dispenser cookies = new Dispenser(5,3);

//Constructor
public VendingMachine() {

    setTitle("Brennan's Vending Machine");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Layout
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1)); //GRID LAYOUT (Button Spaces)

    //Create Lebels
    headingL = new JLabel("WELCOME TO BRENNAN'S VENDING MACHINE", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    selectionL = new JLabel("Click a button for your selection", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    //Create Buttons
    bHandler = new ButtonHandler();

    candyB = new JButton("candy");
    candyB.addActionListener(bHandler);
    chipsB = new JButton("chips");
    chipsB.addActionListener(bHandler);
    gumB = new JButton("gum");
    gumB.addActionListener(bHandler);
    cookiesB = new JButton("cookies");
    cookiesB.addActionListener(bHandler);
    adminB = new JButton("Admin");
    adminB.addActionListener(bHandler);
    exitB = new JButton("EXIT");
    exitB.addActionListener(bHandler);

    //Add objects
    pane.add(headingL);
    pane.add(selectionL);
    pane.add(candyB);
    pane.add(chipsB);
    pane.add(gumB);
    pane.add(cookiesB);
    pane.add(adminB);
    pane.add(exitB);

} //end Constructor

//Listener Event for Buttons
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("EXIT"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("candy")) {
                sellProduct(candy, "Candy");
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("chips")) {
                sellProduct(chips, "Chips");
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("gum")) {
                sellProduct(gum, "Gum");
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("cookies")) {
                sellProduct(cookies, "Cookies");
            }
            else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Admin")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cookie Inventory: " + getInv(cookies));
            }
        }//end actionPerformed

    }//end ButtonHandler

    //Admin Output

    private void sellProduct(Dispenser product, String productName) {
        int itemPrice;

        if(product.getInv() > 0) {
            product.invOut();
            itemPrice = product.getProductCost();
            register.cashIn(itemPrice);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Get Your " + productName, ". Item Dispensed", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This item is out of stock.");
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    VendingMachine vending = new VendingMachine();
    System.out.println(candy.getInv());
}//end main

}//end class
```

**Inventory Handler Class**

```
package vendingmachine;

public class Dispenser {

//Instance Vars
private int productInv = 10;
private int productCost;

//Constructors
public Dispenser() {
    productInv = 10;
    productCost = 1;
}//end Inv()

public Dispenser(int productInv, int productCost) {
    this.productInv = productInv;
    this.productCost = productCost;
}//end Overloaded

//get Method
public int getInv() {
    return productInv;
}//end getInv()

public int getProductCost() {
    return productCost;
}

//Increment Inventory
public void invOut() {
    productInv -= 1;
}
}//end class
```

**Cash Handler Class**

```
package vendingmachine;

public class Register {
//Instance Vars
private int cashBalance = 500;

//Constructor
public Register() {
    cashBalance = 500;
}//end Register()

public Register(int cashBalance) {
    this.cashBalance = cashBalance;
}//end overloaded

//get method
public int getBalance() {
    return cashBalance;
}

//Increment balance for sale
public void cashIn(int cashDepo) {
    cashBalance =+ cashDepo;
}
}//end class
```

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getInv(Dispenser)
  location: class VendingMachine.ButtonHandler
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cookie Inventory: " + getInv(cookies));

Comment: Edited and posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error itself is pretty clear.

It doesn't find a method called `getInv` with a `Dispenser` as argument.
You're calling the `getInv` method here: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cookie Inventory: " + getInv(cookies));`

While you have defined a `getInv`(entory?) method in the `Dispenser` class without any argument. So `cookies.getInv();` should be the right call.

Comment: You are a saint thank you, it has been a VERY long day.